# Laravel: Exibir row() ao invés de result()

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estou usando o Laravel 7.3.
Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
$data = DB::table(self::TABLE_CATEGORIES)
        ->select('id')
        ->where('slug', $slug)
        ->get();
```

E o resultado seria o seguinte:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

E eu gostaria de obter somente o resultado

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10

        )
)
```

Neste caso, quando eu fizer echo $items->id, teria o resultado, mas do jeito anterior eu teria que usar um foreach() para obter o resultado.

Como pode ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_pluck)

```
<?php
DB::table('...')
    // ...
    ->pluck('id');
```

---

P.S.: com o Laravel é recomendado ter um Model para cada tabela, assim você não precisa passar o nome da tabela em todas as chamadas. Se houvesse um Model `Categories` poderia chamar com `Categories::pluck('id')`.